# ssh not expanding ~ correctly?

Tags: ssh

So for permission reasons, I have had to change my default home directory to a non-standard location.

I did `export HOME=/non/standard/home` and then confirmed this was working with

```
$ cd ~
$ pwd
/non/standard/home
```

Even though `man ssh` says that it looks in `~/.ssh` for keys and identity files, it doesn't seem to:

```
$ ls ~/.ssh
cluster_key  cluster_key.pub  config
$ ssh host
Could not create directory '/home/myname/.ssh'.
The authenticity of host 'host (<ip address deleted>)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is <finerprint deleted>.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/myname/.ssh/known_hosts).
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic).
```

What does it insist on looking in `/home/myname`? The man page state that is consults the `HOME` environment variable. Using the `-F` option also fails to work.

```
$ ssh -version
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
Bad escape character 'rsion'.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run "export" command you actually affect only your process of BASH/SH. When .ssh looks for it it has it's own instance and thus looks in the default directory. You need to run the command `usermod -m -d /path/to/new/home/dir userNameHere` (change the user that .ssh uses, probably admin)

Comment: Ah, well I can't run that command because I don't have permission. :(

Comment: Did you try "sudo" and the command? If you still can't run it then you don't have permission to change the home dir of .ssh

Comment: I have unprivileged access. It's annoying that SSH doesn't respect the $HOME env varibale. Git does at least.

Comment: when you run from your command line "git ..." then it opens a console with your env variables whereas when ssh does it it has it's own and it just doesn't know you've changed a variable.